# Object and Class Communication

Tags: c#

I've been looking up different ways to implement communication between objects and classes in a way that maintains a decoupled, encapsulated, object-oriented approach. What I've found tends to be focused on a specific implementation and I've never seen a comparison, nor the relative pros and cons of the methods. I'm also sure that I'm not aware of them all. In addition my particular application is heavily reliant on user input (game development) and that adds another factor to the mix.

The basic and least appealing method to me was static classes and variables where each object and class accesses a centralized listing of variables. This obviously gets massively crowded very quickly and is far too unwieldy to be practical for anything other than minor applications in my view. I also looked into MVC and MVVC (enough to pick up only the basics) but from what I saw they wouldn't be suitable for the constant input and mechanics necessary for a game loop. Finally, my current method of choice is an event system where a static class contains functions that add delegates to a particular event and when the event is called all those functions are executed. My current implementation is basically something like this:

```
public static class EventManager {

    private static Dictionary<EVNT, Delegate> eventTable = new Dictionary<EVNT, Delegate>();

    public static void AddHandler(EVNT evnt, Action action)
    {
        if (!eventTable.ContainsKey(evnt)) eventTable[evnt] = action;
        else eventTable[evnt] = (Action)eventTable[evnt] + action;
    }

    public static void AddHandler<T>(EVNT evnt, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (!eventTable.ContainsKey(evnt)) eventTable[evnt] = action;
        else eventTable[evnt] = (Action<T>)eventTable[evnt] + action;
    }
    //More multi-variable overloads...

    public static void Broadcast(EVNT evnt)
    {
        Delegate d;
        if (eventTable.TryGetValue(evnt, out d))
        {
            Action action = d as Action;
            if (action != null) action();
        }
    }

    public static void Broadcast<T>(EVNT evnt, T param)
    {
        Delegate d;
        if (eventTable.TryGetValue(evnt, out d))
        {
            Action<T> action = d as Action<T>;
            if (action != null) action(param);
        }
    }

    public static void RemoveHandler(EVNT evnt, Action action)
    {
        if(eventTable[evnt] != null)
            eventTable[evnt] = (Action)eventTable[evnt] - action;
        if (eventTable[evnt] == null)
            eventTable.Remove(evnt);
    }

    public static void RemoveHandler<T>(EVNT evnt, Action<T> action)
    {
        if (eventTable[evnt] != null)
            eventTable[evnt] = (Action<T>)eventTable[evnt] - action;
        if (eventTable[evnt] == null)
            eventTable.Remove(evnt);
    }
}
```

Are there different or better ways to accomplish this 'decoupling' of objects and classes? What other ways can I implement communication, whether or not it's inferior, and how can I best follow object-oriented practices in doing so?

Comment: Have you looked at MassTransit?  http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/configuration/quickstart.html Are you looking at staying in-process only?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately an outside connection isn't an option for most of my development work, but that does look like an interesting solution to explore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might benefit from using the built-in IObserver and IObservable interfaces and implementing the observer pattern, letting your observable push notifications to subscribed observers. Take a look at this example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee850490%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You may also want to look at the reactive extensions library linked to in the article as well, but they are a bit more involved.

Comment: Thanks for the link, a good read. I'm not positive but I was under the impression that the event system was basically an implementation of the observer pattern or mediator pattern. Is there any specific benefits to putting the notifications into the broadcasting classes?

Comment: @cjmarsh I think that depends on the scope of the methods whose delegates are registered in the manager. You could run into issues if you registered methods that change global state significantly, with very few guards against doing so. You can use the observer pattern to limit this by not accessing state directly from the observers, only that state which has been passed in to an observer's method by the observable.

Comment: Another way to look at it is the concept of Broadcast()--in your static class it's more like "Run()"...this event manager is not really broadcasting, it's a runner for void methods. It doesn't know anything about the objects that have registered events in it. This works as long as your entire design pattern is "transaction script," but if you require coordination of state across method calls, you run into issues. (Symptom: you have to call methods in a specific order)